# App Attest and Play Integrity Pricing quotes and where to find it

Tags: android, ios

App Attest and Play Integrity daily quote is 10,000 requests but I want to know how much would be if it reaches 100,000 or 1,000,000? I can't find it because it wants me to fill up the quote form. Just need rough estimate.

Comment: It is still free.  You aren't requesting a *quote* you are requesting an increased *quota* - The number of calls you are permitted to make

Comment: @Paulw11 oh, thats awesome!